# Cannot manage to match property

Tags: org-mode

I have a orgmode file that looks like this :

```
* Amanda
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: Amanda
:AMTYPE_ALL: IMPROVEMENT DEBUG NewFUNCTIONS
:AMTOOLS_ALL: MINIDB DOCPUBLISH TABLES CONSOLIDATION
:AMMAN_ALL: HMI TOOLS PROCESS
:END:

** Todo
*** TODO Evensong's magisterial work on the Amazon :science:read:BIB:
SCHEDULED: <2010-11-20 Sat>
[2010-11-16 Tue 23:11]
:PROPERTIES:
:BIB_AUTHOR: Walter Evensong
:BIB_TITLE: Mysteries of the Amazon
:BIB_PAGES: 1234
:BIB_PUBLISHER: Humbug University Press
:END:

Lots of good stuff on Brazil.
*** TODO 2 :science:read:BIB:
SCHEDULED: <2010-11-20 Sat>
[2010-11-16 Tue 23:11]
:PROPERTIES:
:BIB_AUTHOR: Walter Evensong
:BIB_TITLE: Mysteries of the Amazon
:BIB_PAGES: 1234
:BIB_PUBLISHER: Humbug University Press
:END:

Lots of good stuff on Brazil.
```

I would like to search first for : `BIB_AUTHOR="Walter Evensong"` but the following sequence leads to a blank buffer :

```
C-c a m
```

Type in minibuffer :

```
BIB_AUTHOR="Walter Evensong"
```

Result :

[image: Result from match query]

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- `C-c a m` acts on agenda files, so make sure that the file is an agenda file. If it is not, you can add it temporarily with `C-c [`. Use `C-c ]` to remove it from the agenda file list afterwards if desired.
- IIRC, the search string has to be inside single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
 - Works great
 - In windows at least, the double quotes work.

Comment: I meant that the whole query should be enclosed in single quotes `'BIB_AUTHOR="Warren Evensong"'` but I didn't try it out so I may well be misremembering.